# detect boundary lat longs from given list of lat and long in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, heremaps

[image]Am using here map.
I have a list of objects which has all the latitude and longitude of a particular region from a map as below

//Texas points

```
let list = [
  { lat: 36.5098, lng: -103.0559 },
  { lat: 32.0456, lng: -103.0559 },
  { lat: 32.0456, lng: -106.6103 },
  { lat: 30.827, lng: -105.385 },
  { lat: 29.631, lng: -104.4622 },
  { lat: 29.018, lng: -103.1878 },
  { lat: 29.898, lng: -102.3528 },
  { lat: 27.3525, lng: -99.5403 },
  { lat: 25.9106, lng: -97.2943 },
  { lat: 28.3933, lng: -96.5692 },
  { lat: 29.6994, lng: -93.8665 },
  { lat: 33.5523, lng: -94.0423 },
  { lat: 34.5897, lng: -99.9969 },
  { lat: 36.4848, lng: -99.9969 },
  { lat: 36.5098, lng: -103.0559 },
  { lat: 33.3507, lng: -98.283 },
  { lat: 32.4281, lng: -94.8553 },
  { lat: 26.8358, lng: -98.0853 },
  { lat: 30.9512, lng: -98.5247 },
  { lat: 31.4773, lng: -105.2484 }
];
```

Is there a way to find out the boundary points from the above list. Any ideas how to approach this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. This is not a “here’s my requirement, please do my work for me” site.

Comment: @CBroe   I just need a way about how to approach this?

Comment: can you please clarify boundary points? Do you mean 4 extreme corners?

Comment: @Milind Barve Boundary points means all the longest points from the center.
or
the latitude and longitude makes a point. all the points which will make the boundary as you can see in the image attached. The main purpose is to highlight a region. The boundary is not fixed but it is all the extreme points from the list.

Comment: is there a way to find out  all the extreme points from the above list?

Comment: We can find extreme points representing a rectangle by determining (minimum_lat,minimum_long), (minimum_lat,maximum_long), (maximum_lat, minimum_long),  ( maximum_lat, maximum_long).  But I am still not clear if all points representing boundary are given, what more you need?

Comment: I have all the boundary points and all the internal points of a region.

Comment: I have all the boundary points and all the internal points of a region. So do you have any idea how can i differentiate between them

Comment: @MilindBarve Now am able to find the center point of the region from the var list above. ref here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885798/how-to-calculate-the-midpoint-of-several-geolocations-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addPolygonToMap(map) {
  let str = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    str.push(parseFloat(list[i].lat));
    str.push(parseFloat(list[i].lng));
    str.push(0);
  }

  var geoStrip = new H.geo.Strip([...str], "values lat lng alt");
  map.addObject(
    new H.map.Polygon(geoStrip, {
      style: {
        fillColor: "red",
        strokeColor: "#829",
        lineWidth: 4
      }
    })
  );

}
```